# Rails 3 server must be restarted to load changes, class caching is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I recently changed to developing on a new machine (Ubuntu) with an existing rails app. Two times since switching, changes to source files I make have suddenly stopped being updated without restarting the development server. The first time this happened, the problem went away after a few hours, no idea why. The 2nd time's just happened, hasn't corrected itself yet.

I've confirmed that I am in the development environment, and that Rails.application.config.cache_classes == false wherever I check. Killing all ruby process and restarting everything doesn't help.

I saw this topic: [Why does Rails not refresh classes on every request (despite configuration)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720223/why-does-rails-not-refresh-classes-on-every-request-despite-configuration), but since config.threadsafe! is only called in my production environment, I don't see how that could apply. I've also checked that timestamps on the files changes as I update them.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

---

Short addition: Changes to models and controllers require the server to restart. Views don't.

Comment: I am facing the same problem