# Rails 4.1 doesn't autoreload on Vagrant VM

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ruby-on-rails-4.1

After I upgraded my app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1 I noticed that auto reloading wasn't working on my VM but it used to be working, I set eager_load to false and cache_classes to false and removed any calls to the threadsafe! option

Nothing in these threads provided a solution
[Why does Rails not refresh classes on every request (despite configuration)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720223/why-does-rails-not-refresh-classes-on-every-request-despite-configuration)
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382

So I figured my app was doing something weird, but when I created a simple demo app I noticed the same thing https://github.com/benedictfischer09/reload_problem.  The server running on my native machine auto reloads fine but on the VM it doesn't work.

I'm using NFS to share the directory to the VM, can anyone explain what might be happening and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an issue with the VM clock not being synced with the host clock, here's the github discussion https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16678